# How to iterate the list inside get view of list

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview

I have contact list view in my app...I am using Array adapter for this..While updating an already added contact i need to set the check box visibilty to true for already clicked check box..I know get view in adapter will called for every rows of an list...

This is my adapter code

```
class ContactDispAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserMO> {
        private ArrayList<UserMO> userMOs;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ContactDispAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                  ArrayList<UserMO> userMOs) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, userMOs);
            this.userMOs = new ArrayList<UserMO>();
            this.userMOs.addAll(userMOs);

        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView userNameTxtV;
            TextView mobileNumTxtV;
            CheckBox cb;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            // Create a new row view
            if (convertView == null) {
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contactlist, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                // Find the child views.
                holder.userNameTxtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.mobileNumTxtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_number);
                holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
                // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't have
                // to
                // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.

                convertView.setTag(holder);


            }

            // Reuse existing row view
            else {
                // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call
                // findViewById().
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            }

            holder.cb.setTag(userMOs.get(position));
            EventMO eventMO2 = (EventMO) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("eventMO");
            if (eventMO2 != null) {
                List<EventUserRelationMO> eventUserRelationMOs = eventMO2.getEventUserRelationBOs();
                Log.i("relationMO", "MO inside adapter " + eventUserRelationMOs);
               for(EventUserRelationMO eventUserRelationMO:eventUserRelationMOs){
                    int isInvited = eventUserRelationMO.getIsInvited();

                        if (isInvited == 1) {
                            holder.cb.performClick();
                        } else {
                            Log.i("inside ", "false");
                        }

                }
            }

            holder.userNameTxtV.setText(userMOs.get(position).getUserName());
            holder.mobileNumTxtV.setText(userMOs.get(position).getMobileNumber());
            holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;
                    UserMO userMO = (UserMO) checkBox.getTag();
                    userMO.setSelected(checkBox.isChecked());
                    Log.i("is selected", "usermo" + userMO.isSelected());
                    Log.i("mo", "user" + userMO);

                }
            });
            holder.cb.setChecked(userMOs.get(position).isSelected());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Here i am getting event user relation MO  list from data base..From that i am setting check box visibility to true based on is Invited attribute ..

**Here what is my problem is get view called for each row of the contact,So every time the event User Relation MOs get executes...So i can't set the visibility to check box correctly...
For first row of an list i need  to check only the first index of eventUserRelationMOs.....
For second row of list view i need to execute second index of an eventUserRelationMOs....By this only i can set the check box visibilty**

I dont know how to do that..Please help me to find....

Comment: You need to add your existing for loop inside a new for loop!!, i think you have to write your own logic!

Comment: For loop inside for loop..ok i will try this and tell you..Thank you for your response